# How to find Nvidia GPU for CUDA computation with wide support?

Tags: graphics-cards

I bought GTX 960 GPUs but noticed that the are not supported by all my PCs, most notably business PCs. 
I would like to find some well supported GPUs because I am only interested in computation by GPU, not gaming. 
However, I am not sure if I lose some performance if I choose such GPUs. 
Options are only Nvidia's GPUs with CUDA support because the computation is required in Matlab.

Examples of Business PCs

- HP Compaq Pro 6300 Business PC (Intel Chipset Q75) and many other HP PCs with Intel Chipset Q75, Q85, ... Thread [here](https://superuser.com/questions/869600/what-is-the-6-pin-power-connector-on-an-hp-prodesk) about Q85 and [here](https://superuser.com/q/1019536/2005) about Q75.

How can you find GPU for computation with wide support?

Comment: The first step is to figure out *why* your business PCs don't support the GTX 960.  Once you've provided that information, it'll be possible to suggest GPUs they do support, or ways to upgrade them so they can support a GTX 960.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot install any worthwhile computing GPU in a HP Compaq Pro 6300.  Although the mainboard supports PCIe x16, the power supply is only 320 watts, far below what even lower-end computing cards require, and it uses custom connectors, making it impossible to upgrade.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that but still thinking possibilities. No sufficient manual also found about the PC. You may be right that I have to give up with these HP business computers.